# Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, intel-fortran

Get that error mentioned in the title while trying to use cmake on a getdp project. I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 in Windows. I have install the Inter Fortran compiler. Here is more complete error:

```
-- The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 2021.4.0.20210910
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/2021.4.0/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/2021.4.0/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The Fortran compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/2021.4.0/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/*/source/repos/getdp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/devenv.com CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTC_34aef &&
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.3.
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

    Package 'IFLangServicePackage' failed to load.

    Package 'IFLangServicePackage' failed to load.

    The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.

    Use:
    devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | folder | anyfile.ext]  [switches]
```

Some [pages](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/IFLangServicePackage/td-p/937594) ask you to mention path to the compiler. But that didn't work. [Disabling Windows Defender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141492/cmake-with-mingw-on-windows-10-detecting-cxx-compiler-abi-info-failed) didn't work either.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You may need to run your CMake command from the Intel oneAPI command prompt, see: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-setup/using-the-command-line/specifying-the-location-of-compiler-components.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sounded like a good idea. Did not work though. Still getting the same errors: "Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed..."

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Intel C/C++ compilers with Intel Fortran instead of Visual Studio, using the Ninja generator can be a workaround till CMake is bugfixed.

```sh
cmake -G Ninja
```

This would require having [Ninja](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases) on your PATH.

Comment: How would changing the build tool solve compiler detection/testing during CMake configuration?